# CSS margin-left property doesn't exist?

Tags: css, margin

I am trying to center something both horizontally and vertically on my page... I have seen several threads on stackoverflow of people experiencing the same issue, but I tried the solutions posted there (things relating to overflow: hidden, different floats, inline blocks, etc.) but none seem to work.

Here you can see the CSS validation fails:
<http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.applemktcap.com%2Fcss%2Fmain.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en>

margin-left is not a recognized property? if you go to the homepage of that site, <http://applemktcap.com>, you can see the resulting JS applet which is not centered.

I know it has nothing to do with the JS, as I stripped everything out of my site and put some simple text in the container, and it's still shifted towards the right.  Must just be some simple CSS mistake I'm looking right over.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin-leftâ` is not a valid property.  Looks like there is a weird character after "margin-left" that needs to be removed.  It might be best to re-write that line of code.

Your CSS file shows this:

```
margin-leftâ€‹: -350px;
```